# Adding Index when Creating a Table Error 1064

Tags: indexing

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You have an error in your SQL syntax: 
Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near 'ADD INDEX idx_latitude (latitude)
ADD INDEX idx_longitude (longitude)
ADD INDEX ' at line 21
```

My code where I attempt to create these indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE allCountries ( 
geonameid int(15) PRIMARY KEY, 
name varchar(200), 
asciiname varchar(200), 
alternatenames varchar(4000), 
latitude decimal(11,7), 
longitude decimal(11,7), 
fclass char(1), 
fcode varchar(10), 
country varchar(2), 
cc2 varchar(60), 
admin1 varchar(20), 
admin2 varchar(80), 
admin3 varchar(20), 
admin4 varchar(20), 
population int(15), 
elevation int(15) NULL, 
gtopo30 int(15), 
timezone varchar(40), 
moddate date 
ADD INDEX idx_latitude (latitude),
ADD INDEX idx_longitude (longitude),
ADD INDEX idx_fclass (fclass),
) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

I have tried to use `;` after the brackets, which also did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a comma after `moddate`, and not sure you need the ADD.....

```
...
elevation INT(15) NULL, 
gtopo30 INT(15), 
timezone VARCHAR(40), 
moddate DATE, 
INDEX (latitude),
INDEX (longitude),
INDEX (fclass)
```

Or you could create your index in a separate statement after you've created your table, which would probably be easier.

```
CREATE INDEX id_latitude ON allCountries(latitude)
```

Comment: Thanks alot Sam I appreciate you quick reply.

Comment: I added the CREATE INDEX Statement once the table was created and my SQL dumb ran fine without error :D